# Passing Variable From Python Script to Mail Step

Tags: pentaho

Can pentaho pass variables from inside a python script to an email step on the job level? I currently have a job set up in this order start> shell script (my python script)> set variables> mail but when I pass in ${variable} in the email body it shows it like "${variable}" instead of the actual output.

Answer (score 0):

The Pentaho data integration Get Variable and Get Session Variables use metadata strings in either the Unix or Windows formats.  Your question doesn't indicate which OS you're on.  Perhaps its a matter of switching between:

```
${VARIABLE}
%%VARIABLE%%
```

More details on usage are here: [PDI Documentation](https://help.pentaho.com/Documentation/8.2/Products/Data_Integration/Data_Integration_Perspective/Run_Modifiers/Variables)

Comment: Get Variable and Get Session Variables are in the Transformation level. I cannot run a python script in transformation level so i used the job level shell script then used set variable. I am using windows.